# How to parse Number in a specific manner in php

Tags: php, date, date-format

My variable contains following value.

```
$value = 20151205
```

I want to parse year,month and date from this value.

```
[2015,12,05]
```

How can i do this in php?

This format will be fix for as first 4 digit for year then 2 digits for month and same for date.

Comment: `$dto = new DateTime($value); $parsed = [$dto->format('Y'), $dto->format('m'), $dto->format('d')];`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How do you get this number? Or is it a string?

Comment: I tried preg_split and number_format but not getting right output.

Comment: It is getting from database. but in database it is varchar.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php - If it is a varchar you have a string and can split it very preciesly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try string operation :-

```
<?php
$str1='20151205';
$str1=substr_replace($str1, '/', 4, 0);
$str1=substr_replace($str1, '/', 7, 0);
print_r (explode("/",$str1));
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = 20151205;
$dto = new \DateTime($value); 
$newValue = "[" . $dto->format('Y') . "," . $dto->format('m'). "," . $dto->format('d') . ']';
echo $newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date_parse

```
 $arrDateParse = date_parse("20151205");
```

you will get an array like this

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2015
    [month] => 12
    [day] => 5
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)


$value = "[" . $arrDateParse['year'] . "," . $arrDateParse['month']. "," . $arrDateParse['day'] . ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to give another possibility (the other answers in this thread work as well);

```
$date = date("[Y,m,d]", strtotime('20151205'));
```

See also:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php (date formats that works with strtotime() )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php (date function)

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace (regex) approach:

```
$value = 20151205;
$parsed = preg_replace('/^([\d]{4})([\d]{2})([\d]{2})$/', '[$1,$2,$3]', $value);
```

demo:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/28OsIp

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$int="20151205";
$day = substr($int,-1,2);
$month = substr($int,-4,2);
$year = substr($int,0,4);

echo $date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to format the variable as a date like this

```
try {
   $value = (new DateTime($value))->format('\[Y\,m\,d\]');
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
   echo '$Value is not a date value';
}
```

Enclose the code in a Try/Catch block in order to detect if the value in the variable does not correspond to a date.